# How to replace rows with duplicated values in Access?

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have 2 tables and I'd like to substitute rows from Table1 where Customer value is duplicated (for example, B) with a row from Table2 with the same Customer.

Table 1:

```
Customer     cod
   A          2
   B          1
   B          N/A
   C          5
```

Table 2:

```
Customer      cod
   B          123
```

So the result should be:

```
Customer     cod
   A          2
   B          123
   C          5
```

The code could be something like:

```sql
INSERT INTO Table1
   SELECT * 
    FROM Table2, Table1
    WHERE Table1.Customer = Table2.Customer;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First insert wanted data from table2

```
INSERT INTO Table1
SELECT * 
FROM Table2 t21
WHERE (SELECT count(*) 
       FROM Table1 t12 
       WHERE t12.Customer=t21.Customer) > 1;
```

Then remove duuplicates from table1 which are not matching cod from table 2

```
DELETE
FROM Table1 t11
WHERE ((SELECT count(*) 
       FROM Table1 t12
       WHERE t11.Customer = t12.Customer)>1
      AND NOT cod IN (SELECT cod 
                     FROM Table2 t21 
                     WHERE t11.Customer=t21.Customer))
      OR t11.cod IS NULL;
```

Comment: please try again - i fixed typos

Comment: the second query gives me an error unfortunately: Data type mismatch in criteria expression.

Comment: I tried again, works, thanks! Can i ask you what in this case means t21, t12 and t11, t12?

Comment: alias for the tables - important if you use one table more than once